Ts:18033 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values
I am trying to assign an Enum member a value from the env variable but it throws an error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values.

Direct string value intiliaztion works fine , but the value from the env file does not work
export enum MEMBER_SHIP   {
    CC_FREEMIUM_SKU = process.env.EU_CC_FREEMIUM, //'500018126',
    CC_PREMIUM_SKU = '500019693'
} 


CC_FREEMIUM_SKU throws an error.

This is expected behaviour, because currently computed strings (ie more or less anything other than assigning a string literal) are not allowed for enums. Computed values are only allowed for numbers.

This question is similar to: Why computed values are not permitted in an enum?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also the docs on string enums  "In a string enum, each member has to be constant-initialized with a string literal, or with another string enum member." (emphasis by me)

Note that in Typescript, string enums cannot have computed values like process.env.
Numeric enums can have both computed or constant members, but not string enums which must have constant value.
Since process.env.EU_CC_FREEMIUM is only available at runtime, TypeScript compiler cannot resolve it at compile-time and display an error message

Since process.env.EU_CC_FREEMIUM is only available at runtime, TypeScript compiler cannot resolve it at compile-time and display an error message
If it is available at the run time and not available at compile time , then how the numeric value works.? According to this statement..

@TBA While you are right, that computed  string values are not supported, I'm not so sure about your reasoning on the why  it's not supported, because runtime-computed values are perfectly valid for numeric enum values ... You can even do something like enum Foo { bar = Math.random() }

You can try enum Foo { bar = Math.random().toString() } and you will get an error: numeric values can be computed at run-time, but not string values

Yeah, but you can do enum Foo { bar = Math.random() } and you won't get an error. Thus the argument about the compiler not being able to resolve the value at compile time does not hold, because the numerical random value can't be resolved at compile time either. There most certainly is a reason, why computed strings are not supported as enum values. But it's not the compiler not being able to resolve at compile time ...
